# Problema função endpoint R

Tags: r, data

Estou trabalhando com esse data.frame:

```
St <- data.frame(read.csv2("interest_LastMonthDay.csv"))
        Date     AAA_S.t.    Date.1 BBB_S.t.    Date.2 CCC_S.t.
1   27/12/88      1,80400  28/12/88   0,8368  28/12/88   0,0080
2   28/12/88      1,78900  29/12/88   0,8386  29/12/88   0,0079
3   29/12/88      1,78950  30/12/88   0,8384  30/12/88   0,0080
4   30/12/88      1,80850  2/01/89        ND  2/01/89        ND
5   2/01/89           ND   3/01/89    0,8398  3/01/89    0,0081
6   3/01/89       1,82250  4/01/89    0,8389  4/01/89    0,0080
7   4/01/89       1,80700  5/01/89    0,8407  5/01/89    0,0080
8   5/01/89       1,79700  6/01/89    0,8367  6/01/89    0,0079
9   6/01/89       1,78000  9/01/89    0,8354  9/01/89    0,0079
10  9/01/89       1,76360  10/01/89   0,8327  10/01/89   0,0079
11  10/01/89      1,76370  11/01/89   0,8328  11/01/89   0,0079
12  11/01/89      1,78100  12/01/89   0,8356  12/01/89   0,0079
13  12/01/89      1,78400  13/01/89   0,8342  13/01/89   0,0079
```

Quero  deixar apenas os ultimos valores de cada mês. Para isso usei a função endpoint:

```
St_GBP<-St[,c(1:2)];St_GBP<-St_GBP[endpoints(St_GBP$Date, on = "months"), ]
```

Ela me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Error in try.xts(x, error = "must be either xts-coercible or timeBased") : 
  must be either xts-coercible or timeBased
```

Como posso contornar isso?

Acho que o problema esta nas colunas das datas que são `factors`. Mas não consegui resolver:

```
class(St$Date);class(St$Date.1);class(St$Date.2)
[1] "factor"
[1] "factor"
[1] "factor"
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema está na leitura dos dados. Em primeiro lugar, você precisa utilizar `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` para que o R não converta as colunas não-numéricas em fatores.

Você também precisa informar o `na.string = "ND"`, já que os dados estão gravados com `ND` como `NA`. Feito isso, você precisa converter as colunas de data para formato de tempo que o R reconheça, usando `strptime`. O código completo (lendo os dados a partir do texto) fica assim:

```
St <- read.table(text="Date     AAA_S.t.    Date.1 BBB_S.t.    Date.2 CCC_S.t.
1   27/12/88      1,80400  28/12/88   0,8368  28/12/88   0,0080
2   28/12/88      1,78900  29/12/88   0,8386  29/12/88   0,0079
3   29/12/88      1,78950  30/12/88   0,8384  30/12/88   0,0080
4   30/12/88      1,80850  2/01/89        ND  2/01/89        ND
5   2/01/89           ND   3/01/89    0,8398  3/01/89    0,0081
6   3/01/89       1,82250  4/01/89    0,8389  4/01/89    0,0080
7   4/01/89       1,80700  5/01/89    0,8407  5/01/89    0,0080
8   5/01/89       1,79700  6/01/89    0,8367  6/01/89    0,0079
9   6/01/89       1,78000  9/01/89    0,8354  9/01/89    0,0079
10  9/01/89       1,76360  10/01/89   0,8327  10/01/89   0,0079
11  10/01/89      1,76370  11/01/89   0,8328  11/01/89   0,0079
12  11/01/89      1,78100  12/01/89   0,8356  12/01/89   0,0079
13  12/01/89      1,78400  13/01/89   0,8342  13/01/89   0,0079", 
                 dec = ",", na.strings = "ND", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

St$Date <- strptime(St$Date, format="%d/%m/%y")

library(xts)
St[endpoints(St$Date, on = "months"), ]

#         Date AAA_S.t.   Date.1 BBB_S.t.   Date.2 CCC_S.t.
#4  1988-12-30   1.8085  2/01/89       NA  2/01/89       NA
#13 1989-01-12   1.7840 13/01/89   0.8342 13/01/89   0.0079
```

PS.: Duas dicas para quando for fazer perguntas:

1. Sempre coloque os pacotes que estiver utilizando, se tiver código que não é do base-R.
2. Verifique se o seu código é reprodutível, você começou usando `St` e mudou para `St_GBP`.